# ASP w/ spa react dotnet build takes a long time

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, build

I have a ASP spa project and I'm running `dotnet build` to build my app. From logs I've observed the following:

```
added 1970 packages in 13.567s
     1>Done Building Project "path.csproj" (default targets).

Build succeeded.
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:03:10.17
```

It builds the c# code really fast, around 3 seconds and I'm using `npm ci` which takes `~15s` as should in the logs. But after the `npm ci` finishes, the build process takes a couple of minutes to finish.

```xml
  <Target Name="DebugEnsureNodeEnv" BeforeTargets="Build" Condition=" '$(Configuration)' == 'Debug' And !Exists('$(SpaRoot)node_modules') ">
    <!-- Ensure Node.js is installed -->
    <Exec Command="node --version" ContinueOnError="true">
      <Output TaskParameter="ExitCode" PropertyName="ErrorCode" />
    </Exec>
    <Error Condition="'$(ErrorCode)' != '0'" Text="Node.js is required to build and run this project. To continue, please install Node.js from https://nodejs.org/, and then restart your command prompt or IDE." />
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Restoring dependencies using 'npm'. This may take several minutes..." />
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(SpaRoot)" Command="npm ci" />
  </Target>
```

I've tried to run it with different verbosity levels to understand what it is doing meanwhile but I can't figure it out. Why does it take 3 minutes when it finished the last building step?

Comment: I suggest you could try to disable the spa 
`// if (env.IsDevelopment()) // { // spa.UseReactDevelopmentServer(npmScript: "start"); // }`

And then you could run npm start manually.

Comment: What does this have to do with building the project?